# checking for valid threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

If you have a saved thread id (obtained using the boost::thread::get_id() function), how can you check to see if that thread is currently running?

Comment: what's your definition of "currently running" ?

Comment: You want to do it programatically or through a tool?

Comment: I'm new to boost, so sometimes I don't even know the right question to ask. By "running" I mean whether or not a thread with a particular id has completed its processing (for example, if you pass it a function - once that function exits). I hope that answer makes sense with respect to your question. I'm probably missing something. I want to be able to programatically save an ID (because I can get that from within a thread), then check that ID at some point later to see if the thread has completed. The other answers below assume I have a handle already (which I don't).

Answer (score 1):

Dunno if this helps, but if you store a pointer to the boost::thread, you could query [boost::thread::joinable](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.joinable)?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (thread->joinable() && ! thread->timed_join(**zero_time here**)) {
  /* still running */
} else {
  /* not running */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not do so, at least not portably.

You need to set up a shared variable that the thread writes to just before it ends.  That variable can be read by other threads to determine the target thread's status.  You'll need to synchronize this variable with atomics or a mutex.

Comment: I think I'm trying to do something I shouldn't be doing from an object oriented standpoint. I was trying to access information about other threads from within a thread (not the main one), which doesn't seem smart. The other answers assume I have a handle to the threads (please see my comment above).

Comment: Programming philosophy aside, thread::id just doesn't have the API you're looking for.  All you can do is compare one thread::id to another.  It is mainly useful for checking to see if a function is running the same thread twice in a row, by comparing with a local static thread::id.  However could create a map<thread::id, state> and have threads update the map with their current state (running, finished).  Note however that after a detached thread has finished running, and after a thread has been joined, its thread::id may be used again by another thread.